# Get digest hash of docker image before downloading

Tags: docker, security, hash

My end goal is to be able to read a hash of a container before and after pulling it from Docker hub to verify that the image downloaded from dockerhub is the same image that I now have on my computer. I understand that it sounds redundant verification of the remote and local file is important to me in this instance.

I can read the image once its downloaded by doing `docker images --digests` which gives me a hash I can use, but I do not know where I can find something to compare to on docker hub

```
docker images --digests                                                                            
REPOSITORY                             TAG                       DIGEST                                                                IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk           3.1.410-nanoserver-1809   sha256:c579393a1cb901b13355e985271c94c35cde0bd49f8640ace97f16f4fa641bac   9cba62e9195e   8 days ago    760MB
mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore   ltsc2019-amd64            sha256:ad4ef35c9cfa9d3da0a05bfaa0901e08ee2027ea10d8487490caa9d520c46a8a   5b60ac4e9e92   11 days ago   5.62GB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a tool like `skopeo` where you can run a command like this

```
skopeo inspect docker://docker.io/alpine:latest
```

It queries the repository and returns data as JSON. The start of the data for an image includes the digest.

```
{
    "Name": "docker.io/library/alpine",
    "Digest": "sha256:234cb88d3020898631af0ccbbcca9a66ae7306ecd30c9720690858c1b007d2a0",
    "RepoTags": [
        "2.6",
        "2.7",
```

If you're feeling adventurous you can also query the registry API yourself. The docs are here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

Comment: Thank you, skopeo was the way to go!